# Why is -1 being used when a method does not return a value?

Tags: javascript

This statement simply checks an "@" symbol in a textbox.

```
if (string1.indexOf("@")==-1){
 alert("Please input a valid email address!")
 document.example.email.focus()
```

This. `if (string1.indexOf("@")==-1){` why do we use -1 instead of 0.

it baffles me, since 0 is been used almost everywhere as a 'null' or 'empty' value.

Comment: this question is like a slow search engine result :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *most* programming languages, indexes are zero-based, meaning that the first position in an index (again in *most* programming languages, a string is an index of characters) will be 0 - hence 0 can't be used to indicate nothing was found anywhere.

---

To help clarify:

A `string` is an index of `chars` (characters, or single-symbol types). So, `"hi@ho.com"` is an index containing 9 positions:

```
[0] = 'h'
[1] = 'i'
[2] = '@'
[3] = 'h'
[4] = 'o'
[5] = '.'
[6] = 'c'
[7] = 'o'
[8] = 'm'
```

Because indexes in JavaScript are *zero-based* they always start with their first position being 0. `indexOf` uses -1 to tell you that it couldn't find the `@` anywhere because it can't use 0 since 0 is actually the first position of the index.

Even if `strings` weren't indexes *most* languages would still use -1 to indicate it couldn't find the character and 0 to indicate the first position for reasons of tradition and de facto standards.

In the above example, `indexOf("@")` would return 2, not 3. Again, because indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 4):

Because if the `@` is found at the very start of `string1`, its index would be 0 even though it is found.

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` returns the first **zero-based index position** of the string passed.

- If `string1` starts with `@` then it will return `0`.
- If `string1`'s 2nd character is `@` it will return `1`
- 3rd character will return `2`
- 4th character will return `3`
- etc etc...

`-1` is returned if there are no matches because its impossible to have a `-1` zero-based index position.

`0` cannot be used as this will clash with the result if the string starts with `@`

---

More information of `indexOf` can be found here:

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-indexOf.php

Answer (score 0):

It's because the characters in a string are indexed left to right, and 0 is the first character.

Therefore, you'd expect a range of results from 0 to string length - 1 if you found a character/string and it would seem logical to keep the return type the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is -1 because that means that it couldnt find the string or set of chars you were looking for. Since strings are like an array of characters, like in any other array, the index always starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to help you understand better:

```
var email = 'mymail@server.com';
//  indexes  0123456789...
```

As you can see the index of the `m` is zero, as it is at the beginning of the string, so in this example `indexOf('@')` would return `6`, because the `@` is at the 6<sup>th</sup> position in the string.

so, if the `@` is not found, what would we return? Returning zero indicates that something *was* found, so we want to return a non-zero value, which according to `indexOf` is `-1`

```
var invalidEmail = 'myEmail';
// indexes      -1 |0123456
```